# Resize different images to square without white space

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resize

I am trying to force all the images in the product grid to square. The database serves images from ultra wide to ultra high ratios.

i'm trying the following:

```
$productImage = $imagehelper->init($product, 'category_page_grid')
                ->constrainOnly(false)
                ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                ->keepFrame(false)
                ->resize(400, 400)
                ->getUrl();
            ?>
```

But whatever i try i always seem to be getting white space for the images that have a high image ratio (side note i do not want the aspect ratio to be distorted) .. what i want is magento to look for a square in the middle of the image and just cut off the rest, no matter if it's high or wide.

anyone have an idea?